Issue accessing components in Git subtree - Error: Cannot find module
I am encountering an issue while trying to access a component from a Git subtree in my Svelte project. Here’s a simplified view of my project structure:
root
- .subtree
  - imports
    - ui
      - Searchbar.svelte
- imports
  - ui
    - App.svelte

I am attempting to import Searchbar.svelte from the .subtree directory into App.svelte. However, I keep getting an error: Error: Cannot find module /.subtree/imports/ui/ThreeColumnLayout.svelte.
Here’s the snippet from App.svelte where I attempt to import and use Searchbar.svelte:
<script>
  import Searchbar from "/.subtree/imports/ui/ThreeColumnLayout.svelte";
  // Assuming these are required props for Searchbar
  export let placeholder = "Search Here...";
</script>

<div class="relative">
  <label for="search" class="absolute flex items-center left-2 top-2 justify-center">
    <!-- Placeholder SVG code -->
    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="m21 21-5.2-5.2m0 0A7.5 7.5 0 1 0 5.2 5.2a7.5 7.5 0 0 0 10.6 10.6" />
    </svg>
  </label>

  <!-- Use the Searchbar component -->
  <Searchbar {placeholder} />
</div>

I have tried different file paths such as ../../.subtree/imports/ui/ThreeColumnLayout.svelte and /.subtree/imports/ui/ThreeColumnLayout.svelte, but the error persists.

What bundler/build tools are you using?

I am using Meteor as my build tool and framework. Both the repositories (subtree and parent) were created using meteor create --svelte simple-todos-svelte --prototype. @brunnerh

Meteor does not natively recognize subdirectories outside of its usual imports, maybe it is the issue. You can link it like this: ln -s .subtree/imports/ui imports/subtree-ui 
